# Default to an option on a dropdown option

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu to default to a certain value depending on an employee number, I have managed to get it to say it but it's not the right option as the options are pulled in from on MS SQL server, so it just created 2 options for 'Labour' for example, there's the one from SQL which works but then one that's created as it's a default option but then it doesn't let me post the form properly.

```
elseif ($_SESSION['employeeNo'] == '330'){
echo "<option selected>Labour</option>";
while ($costrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($coststmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$costOption = $costrow["Cost_Centres"];
$costArea = $costrow["Area"];
echo "<option value='" . $costOption . " (" . $costArea . ")'> $costOption </option>";
}
    }
```

[image: Shows that the option 'Labour' is created]

[image: Then the option 'Labour' appears again]

Labour 2 is from the SQL server, which is the one I need it to default to so that I can use it to write back to the database. Otherwise, it thinks that that drop down is not set.

All help is appreciated cheers.

Comment: You just need to add `selected` to the option that matches your condition. So in `echo "<option value='"...` concatenate `selected` if the condition is met.

Comment: Obviously it creates two options Labour if you put one in manually and the other comes from the database. Remove the first echo. Put in the loop a variable `$selected='';` If your requirement is met, set `$selected='selected';` And put `$selected` in the option string;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just output `selected="selected"` for the default option.

I removed the useless concatenations for clarity, and used `$selected` as a variable to separate concerns. Of course you may want to organize the code differently, and change the test `$costOption == 'Labour'`.

```
elseif ($_SESSION['employeeNo'] == '330') {
  while ($costrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($coststmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $costOption = $costrow["Cost_Centres"];
    $costArea = $costrow["Area"];
    $selected = ($costOption == 'Labour') ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value='$costOption ($costArea)' $selected> $costOption </option>";
  }
}
```

If you never encountered it, `(condition) ? X : Y` is the ternary operator. If `condition` is true, `X` is chosen, otherwise `Y` is chosen.